# Using fetch requests on background threads with Core Data

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, core-data, nsoperation

I want to use one `ManagedObjectContext` for the main thread and another, separate one for the background thread using `NSOperation`, as Apple suggests.  And, each `ManagedObjectContext` shares the same persistent store.

Fetching could happen on the main thread because I use Core Data to populate a table view.

In the background, I need to access an `NSManagedObject` property that stores the name of an image.  Then, the background thread will create and cache these images, which is the main reason for having the background thread.

Given such, is there any danger (like locking) if both threads attempt to access the persistent store because both could be fetching data from it the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two different MOCs can access the same PSC at the same time for reads.

However for writes, you need to `lock` and `unlock` your persistent store coordinator if there is a chance of concurrent writes.

Comment: Sure? I haven't read anything about that in the apple docs. Can you point me to your source?

Comment: I never ever found it in the docs.  It was hard earned experience and some long debugging sessions.  It's easy enough to repro if you make two different threads constantly write to the same NSPSC

Comment: sample code in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236860/app-freeze-on-coredata-save/5237031#5237031

Comment: I couldn't find it in the documentation either, but when testing, it appears 2 different MOCs can read data from the persistent store at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Each thread requires its own managed object context, but all threads need to share a single persistent store coordinator - that will take care of potential issues you're describing. See additional information in the [Core Data Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#/).

Answer (score 0):

As long as each thread uses its own `NSManagedObjectContext`, it's perfectly safe to have them share an `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`. `NSManagedObjectContext` will deal with doing all the appropriate locking of the persistent store as needed. However, you do have to be careful not to share `NSManagedObject`s between threads.